# Angular 2 Is there a way to transform (click)="" to a href on method?

Tags: angular, redirect, click

In my Angular 2
All my redirect routing have been done on `(click)=" event"`. That's fine, but i need to mouse wheel redirect / and link context menu ( like "open link in a new tab menu").

How can i do this in a best way? Can i bind this click event on routeLink just for stylization, how should i bind this event on routeLink.

```
<a routerLink="" (click)="OnDash()" class="default_link">
```

bref
I have method using for redirecting `(click)="OnDash()"` , but i haven't link `'/dash'`, i need this menu

[image]

Comment: im not sure i understand your question, but if you need a route link, you can use routerLink instead of click or href .
or you could do your own context menu and handle it with the function as well 
`<div (contextmenu)="onRightClick()"></div>

onRightClick() {
    return false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to handle on DOM, using `<a>` hyperlink tag and correspondent Angular directive:

```
<nav>
     <a class="nav-item" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</nav>
```

, for example. You add `routerLink` directive which provides you with route here.

Check out this https://angular.io/guide/router .

Comment: Can i do it without link ('/dashboard') ? I just have got a method that redirect me to /dashboard. How can bind it on routerLink ?
I need routerLink="OnDashboard()"; Is it possible ?